# Relationship between switching frequency and controller's crossover frequency in buck SMPS

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck, control-system

Context: tuning the control loop of a buck SMPS. I specicifally have a TI TPS40200-based circuit in mind, but I think this applies to SMPS design in general.

Quoting from [Type 2 compensation network](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/20219/type-2-compensation-network):

> Mr. Maniktala suggests that the loop gain transfer function of the
> switcher intersect the 0 dB point at approximately 1/6th the switching
> frequency, with a slope of -1.

I have heard this before from another engineer, but did not get a chance to ask why. What is the reason the crossover frequency of the control network should be a fraction of the switching frequency? Why specifically around 1/5th or 1/6th?

Are there any other desirable traits when designing a compensation network for an SMPS controller other than the most basic criterion of >45 degree phase margin for system stability?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A switch mode power supply is essentially a sampled-data system, therefore the theoretical maximum bandwidth is one half the switching frequency.  Practically the phase and transport lag there make it impossible to close the loop there, so 1/5 to 1/10th the switching frequency is a good rule of thumb.

There are many other considerations in compensating an SMPS- Gain margin, conditional stability, current vs. voltage mode, slope compensation, transient response, etc.

Check out www.ridleyengineering.com, there are lots of good free tutorials and papers there.

Comment: Ah. So I was overlooking the fact that a sampled-data system need not be a digital control system. You can only update a PWM duty cycle once per period, and that makes this a sampled-data system because you output is sampled, even if the controller itself is almost completely analog circuitry. This is a case where the terms 'discrete-time' and 'digital' are far from interchangeable.

Comment: Exactly! You can use a zero-order hold transfer function in the z domain as part of the control loop model of a SMPS to model the sampling effects.